what does that exactly mean 每天结束反省自己?
每天结束反省自己 - this is one of the advises for those who found themselves in poverty and are struggling to escape. I am trying to grasp its meaning, but direct translation, obviously, does not unwrap it. Could you please advise - how do you perceive that ? Thank you in advance.

What about the meaning are you struggling with? It seems that a basic dictionary search would give you [every day] + [end] + [introspection] + [yourself]. It should be fairly manageable? We cannot know how to help if you don't tell us your point of confusion.

The importance of punctuation : 每天，结束反省自己(x) ；每天结束，反省自己 (o)

@Iames  That's a good one :)

准确地说应该是每天结束时反省自己或者每天结束的时候反省自己。
意思是：每天晚上(睡觉前)自己进行思考，总结，反思，反省。
与之相关最早出现的是

曾子曰：“吾日三省吾身：为人谋而不忠乎？与朋友交而不信乎？传不习乎？”


每天反省是指我们在每天结束时，
Reflecting every day means we, at the end of each day,
停下手中的事情，
(should) stop whatever we are doing
回忆一天的所作所为，
(and) recall what we have done and how,
对自己的行为进行审视和总结。
examine our behaviour and make a summary.
反省的目的是发现自己的不足和错误，
The purpose of reflection is to discover ones insufficiencies and errors,
使自己更加完善和进步。
(in order to) make oneself more refined and improve oneself.
Should one find oneself to be perfect, one may safely ignore the above!
